# Windows and event subscription (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, events

Is there a way to suscribe one window event for look when another window close itself? I need to ask some details in the other window, once I get the details, then I close that window, the main window needs to know that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whichever class constructs the window should be able to subscribe an eventhandler from the handler window to the .Closing event of the window you want it to respond to.

```
SomeWindow window = new SomeWindow();
window.Closing += otherWindow.ClosingEventhandler;
window.Show();
```

Comment: I was studying events, event handling and all that stuff but doesn't understand until saw your example. Pragmatic, concise and precise, thanks a lot!